# Understanding small asm code with a strange constant

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, reverse-engineering, nasm, yasm

I am working through the riddles of "xchg rax,rax" ([xchg.xorpd.net](http://xchg.xorpd.net)). Those are riddles about x86_64 assembly, where you have to understand what code pieces do. This is riddle number 0x15:

```
mov      rdx,0xffffffff80000000
add      rax,rdx
xor      rax,rdx
```

It seems like this code is meant to enhance the value inside rax in some way, though I don't fully understand how.
I tried to give in some inputs and outputs, but I didn't yet manage to understand what this code does. What is this 0xffffffff80000000 number?
Could someone point me in the correct direction to the solution? I'm really curious about this one.

Comment: Without context (which xorpd doesn't provide), it's hard to say.  Still, if you take a 32bit number and set the most significant bit, that gives you -2,147,483,648.  Representing that value with a 64bit number gives you FFFFFFFF80000000.  And what significance might that have?  Dunno.  The only use I can see it a really weird way to turn 64bit numbers (positive and negative) into 32bit numbers.  FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what "enhance" is supposed to mean, but assuming the upper half of `rax` is zero, it sign-extends `eax` into `rax`.

First, observe that adding 0x80000000 and then xoring with 0x80000000 would do exactly nothing to `eax`. They both invert the highest bit, and an even number of inversions cancel out.

But it's 64bit, so something happens: the addition can carry into the lowest bit of the upper half.

To make it simpler, let's pretend they wrote this:

```
mov edx, 0x80000000
add rax, rdx
xor rax, rdx
mov rdx, 0xffffffff00000000
add rax, rdx
xor rax, rdx
```

Now the first two instructions sign-extend to 33 bits, putting a copy of the sign of `eax` in the lowest bit of the upper half of `rax`. So the upper half is either 0 or 1, depending on the sign of `eax`.

The last two lines now look a lot like the usual `-x = ~(x - 1)`, but applied only to the upper half, turning that 1 into all ones.

And these steps can be combined, which gives you the original code.

Alternatively, you can think of it as not cutting `rax` in half, but cutting it "just below half", so the negation deal is applied to a 33 bit number starting at the highest bit of `eax`.

Comment: Cool, Sign extension! This is just what CDQE does. Thanks :)

Comment: @dedthecool well sort of, `cdqe` still sign-extends if the upper half is not zero, while this will just go ahead and make a weird result.